# OpenCL Implementation for Intel Core i5 (linux)

Tags: linux, opencl, intel

My laptop's processor is intel core-i5, and am running ubuntu on it. I visited the page: http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl , but I found that the intel opencl implementation does not support the configuration I have.

Can someone please let me know of an opencl implementation which will work for my machine.

Comment: The hardware provider is (usually) the exclusive source for OCL support.  In this case, AMD's SDK might just work with the intel CPU.  BTW, 'core' is listed on the page you linked to.  How do you know it's not supported?

Comment: Intel core processors are supported but only for windows. This is shown on the web page.

Comment: Use AMD SDK, has a software fallback that implements CPU OpenCL in many CPUs. BUt I don't know if it works for linux.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't ever use, but [Beignet](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Beignet/) supposedly supports the Intel GPU on Linux.

Comment: Tested on 3rd Generation Intel Core Processors.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your processor supports at least SSE 2.x the AMD APP SDK mentioned by DarkZeros should work.

Other (open source) alternatives for running OpenCL on an x86 CPU without relying on vendor-dependent implementations are:

- POCL (Portable Compute Language): http://pocl.sourceforge.net/
- libcoprthr: http://www.browndeertechnology.com/coprthr_libocl.htm
- freeocl: http://code.google.com/p/freeocl/ . This one will just use an existing C++ compiler on your platform. This will not yield the most optimized implementation but maybe useful for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The Intel "Version XE 2013 R2" works just fine on my core-i7, ubuntu 12.04. Not with the integrated GPU, though. Have you tried it? AMD's OCL mentioned above runs just fine too, and is a bit faster. At least on with the tests I ran...